# When try to parse xml with attributes getting empty array

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I was trying to serialize xml, the sample structure like this

```
<nodes>
    <node1>87576</node1>
    <node2>10</node2>
    <crsa>
        <crsa x="0">3487</crsa>
        <crsa x="1">0</crsa>
        <crsa x="2">0</crsa>
    </crsa>
    <node3>0</node3>
    <node4>131</node4>
</nodes>
```

This is the generated class.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "nodes")]
public class Nodes
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "node1")]
    public string node1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "node2")]
    public string node2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "node3")] 
    public string node3 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "crsa")]
    public Crsa[] crsa { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "node4")]
    public string node4 { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "crsa")]
public class Crsa
{
    [XmlAttribute("x")]
    public string X { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize the xml to the class, the `crsa` array values are getting empty. The other node values are serialized correctly.
When I generated the class using http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ the `Crsa` is not an array `public Crsa crsa { get; set; }`. I tried with both but the values are getting empty.

Comment: Is that really the XML you have to work with? It appears the `crsa` element has been given two completely different roles to play, being both the container and the contained item.

Comment: @Damien Yes, the node name was same. What was the issue in container and the contained item?

Comment: There's no *specific* issue, per se. It's just that I suspect you'll find that it's this aspect that's tripping up the tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<crsa>` nodes have both an outer element and inner element(s) of the same name.  In order to serialize your `Crsa[]` collection with an outer container element in this manner,  you need to decorate the `crsa` property with [`[XmlArray]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.aspx) instead of [`[XmlElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx):

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "nodes")]
public class Nodes
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "node1")]
    public string node1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "node2")]
    public string node2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "node3")] 
    public string node3 { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("crsa")]
    [XmlArrayItem("crsa")]
    public Crsa[] crsa { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "node4")]
    public string node4 { get; set; }
}
```

The inner [`[XmlArrayItem]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx) attribute sets the name of the nested elements.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EKqIgq).